# Sql Case When multiple colums and multiple condition

Tags: sql, case

I need to change the column value from 2 columns

Example

```
Declare column*A int,  column*B int, columnC int

If columnA = 1, columnB = 1 then columnC = 1

If columnA = 0, columnB = 1 then columnC = 1

If columnA = 1, columnB = 0 then columnC = 1

If columnA = 0, columnB = 0 then columnC = 0
```

I already try below script

```
Column C = (case when (columnA='0') or (columnB='0') then '0' else '1' end)

and

Column C = (case when (columnA\<\>'0') or (columnB\<\>'0') then '1' else '0' end)
```

These 2 methods cannot meet my needs in a single script.

Comment: Besides `or`, you can also use `and` in your conditions. Or, if you want to keep it simple, you could chose to use something like `CASE WHEN ColumnA + ColumnB > 0 THEN ColumnC = 1 ELSE ColumnC = 0 END`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: And perhaps GREATEST() can be used? But why are you doing this - are you going to drop ColA and ColB later?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE statements seem wrong. You check if either of ColumnA or ColumnB are 0, and then set ColumnC to be zero. But if the other column is 1, ColumnC should be 1 (as per your requirement).

This should do the trick, though:

`CASE WHEN (ColumnA + ColumnB > 0) THEN ColumnC = 1 ELSE ColumnC = 0 END`